# Unable to read write information in postgres database via gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have this gorm snippet where I am trying to write/read data into DB

Main function

```
package main
import "studentDetails/gomodule/database"

// Connecting to database
if err := database.Open(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Unable to connect to DB", err)
}
fmt.Println("Connected to DB !!!")

defer database.Close()

database.WriteToDB()
data := database.GetAllFromDB()
fmt.Println("Data from DB", data)
```

Database functions

```
package database
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

type Student struct {
    Id          string `gorm:"type:varchar;primary_key;" json:"student_id"`
    Name        string `gorm:"type:varchar" json:"name"`
    PhoneNumber int    `gorm:"type:varchar" json:"phone_number"`
    EmailId     string `gorm:"type:varchar" json:"email_id"`
    Branch      string `gorm:"type:varchar" json:"branch"`
}

func Open() error {
    var err error
    DB, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "host=127.0.0.1 port=5433 user=postgres dbname=student password=postgres sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Close() error {
    return DB.Close()
}

func WriteToDB() {
    tempMap := Student{Branch: "ISE", EmailId: "chetan@gmail.com", Id: "1234", Name: "Chetan", PhoneNumber: 123456}
    result := DB.Model(&Student{}).Create(tempMap)
    fmt.Println("Data written in the database", result)
}

func GetAllFromDB() *gorm.DB {
    st := Student{}
    result := DB.Find(&st)
    return result
}
```

When I execute the program I do see the database getting connected. But for some reason I am not able to read/write data into the table(It does say record updated but it has not).
I also tried manually inserting table with values to check if get call works. Here is the output:

```
Connected to DB !!!
Data written in the database &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} {1234 Chetan 123456 chetan@gmail.com ISE} using unaddressable value 0 0xc000088000 false 0 {0xc000113db0} 0xc0000d4160 {{0 0} {{map[gorm:started_transaction0xc00042e0780xc0001781c0:0xc00042e080] false}} map[] 0} 0xc0000b8270 <nil> 0xc000099120 false <nil>}
Data from DB &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} 0xc0000b7950 <nil> 1 0xc000088000 false 0 {0xc000113db0} 0xc0000d4840 {{0 0} {<nil>} map[] 0} 0xc0000b8270 <nil> 0xc000099600 false <nil>}
```

Can someone help me out in pointing the mistake am doing. Thanks.

Comment: As a first step to debugging, don't ignore [errors](https://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html) from `DB.Model.Create` or `DB.Find` (or any errors for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

First of all try importing gorm postgres driver to prevent hard coding a lot of configurations with strings
`import "gorm.io/driver/postgres"`

Then modify your Open() function to look like what is below:

```
func Open() error {
    var err error
    connStr := "host=127.0.0.1 port=5433 user=postgres dbname=student password=postgres sslmode=disable"
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(connStr), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Modify WriteToDB to look like this

```
func WriteToDB() {
    tempMap := Student{Branch: "ISE", EmailId: "chetan@gmail.com", Id: "1234", Name: "Chetan", PhoneNumber: 123456}
    result := DB.Model(&Student{}).Create(&tempMap)
    fmt.Println("Data written in the database", result)
}
```

The `Create()` function should hae a pointer of the object you want to persist to database.

However I suggest replacing that entire line with this
`result := DB.Create(&tempMap)` instead of `Calling DB.Model(<pointer>).Create(<pointer>)`